# Correct way of invoking a liquibase context with the new Liquibase version (4.21.1)

Tags: liquibase

There is no documentation that I have seen that illustrates to a developer how to use the Java API to perform a liquibase schema update. With older versions, it would be liquibase.update(), but this has since been deprecated. I need to be able to first run a "createAndInitializeDb" context, and then perform "update" context. How would I do this with Liquibase 4.21.1? Is there an example? I believe that any available library to the public should have usage examples, even if it is open source, as it will help community feedback.

I tried using CommandScope, but it almost appears as though schema changes are getting rolled back or not committed, because earlier in the logs I see DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table creation script, but later on, it fails saying this object does not exist.

```java
private void applyContextTransaction(Database db, ReportingEntity reportingEntity, String context) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("applyContextTransaction for " + context);
    LOGGER.info(context + " :: " + reportingEntity.getConnectionInfo().getDbName());

    CommandScope updateCommand = new CommandScope(UpdateSqlCommandStep.COMMAND_NAME);
    updateCommand.addArgumentValue(DbUrlConnectionCommandStep.DATABASE_ARG, db);
    updateCommand.addArgumentValue(UpdateSqlCommandStep.CHANGELOG_FILE_ARG, changelogPath);
    updateCommand.addArgumentValue(UpdateSqlCommandStep.CONTEXTS_ARG, context);
    updateCommand.execute();
    LOGGER.info("Completed " + context + " for " + reportingEntity.getEntityCode());
}
```

Comment: CommandScope is the better way to execute operations now. Could you include some sample code on how you are calling update and also include the log messages/errors you are seeing?

Comment: I just added a code snippet of how i use it in the above description. This method is called repeatedly for multiple contexts when creating a new database (the contexts are to add users, apply roles, create initial tables (baseline) and initialize data and then finally to update the schema)